# KDE Weather Report not fitting window properly

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, widgets

I am using the KDE Weather Report widget in my task manager. After upgrading from Kubuntu 18.04 to 18.10, I noticed that the contents of the widget are not being properly fit into the window.

The widget used to look like the following:

[image]

But now looks like this (disregard different themes):

[image]

[image]

Where the content doesn't seem to fit the window properly anymore.

I've attempted to change the system DPI, change the desktop and icon themes and readd the widget without anything working. Other KDE widgets seem to fit fine.

Any help would be appreciated.